# delete lines before match except the one above match from stdout

Tags: awk, sed

Looking to use any command to produce the following outcome. Edited for greater clarity. I'm trying to remove any ^abc that is not a line before ^xyz.

stdout:

```
abc def
abc ghi
abc jkl
xyz mno
xyz pqr
abc def
abc ghi
abc jkl
xyz mno
xyz pqr
```

desired result:

```
abc jkl
xyz mno
xyz pqr
abc jkl
xyz mno
xyz pqr
```

Comment: Perhaps edit your code to show exactly where `uniq` would fail here? It would likely be relevant to the `sed` answer. (Is `awk` etc. allowed?)

Comment: before *what* match? before a repeated line? before a line that repeats only in the first column?

Comment: perhaps your example should be a bit more complete (showing the variation in what followed `etc`)

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain a two-line buffer (using a `N` `D` loop) and print the first line before deleting it only if there's a `xyz` in the buffer:

```
$ cat stdout | sed ':a; $!N; /xyz/P; D; ba'
abc jkl
xyz mno
xyz pqr
abc jkl
xyz mno
xyz pqr
```

Comment: Short and sweet; works like a charm; thank you! Now I need to study and assimilate that syntax! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` one-liner.

```
awk '/^abc/ {prev = $0; prevabc = "true"}; /^xyz/ {if (prevabc == "true") {print prev; prevabc = "false" } ; print}' file.txt
```

### Explanation

- `/^abc/ {prev = $0; prevabc = "true"};`: If the line starts with `abc`, don't print it, but instead store the value of the line in the variable `prev`, and indicated that this line started with `abc` by storing `true` in variable `prevabc`.
- `/^xyz/ {if (prevabc == "true") {print prev; prevabc = "false" } ; print}`: If the line starts with `xyz`, the do the following.

  - `if (prevabc == "true") {print prev; prevabc = "false" }`: If the previous line started with `abc` (because `prevabc == "true"`), then print the previous line `prev` and reset `prevabc` to `false`.
  - `print`: Since this line started with `xyz`, then print this line too.